# Bot is spamming the reply within a for loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, bots, discord

I have a command that creates a custom command and adds the command name and response to a JSON file.

```
!addcmd CommandName This is the response
```

This adds it to a JSON file looking like

```
{
  "commands": [
    {
      "user": "Rusty",
      "user_id": "180392440945967104",
      "command_name": "Name",
      "command_reply": "This is the response"
    }
  ]
}
```

I want it so if a user types any of the `command_name` within the `commands` array it will display the `command_reply`. This is my code to do so:

```
  fs.readFile("./jsonFiles/customCommands.json", "utf-8", function(err, data) {
      if (err) throw err;

      var arrayOfCommands = JSON.parse(data);

      for (let i = 0; i < arrayOfCommands.commands.length; i++) {
        if (message.content === arrayOfCommands.commands[i].command_name) {         

  message.channel.sendMessage(arrayOfCommands.commands[i].command_reply);
          return;
        }
      }
  });
```

(ignore the indentation - it's correct in my file). So this code works but when I type the `command_name` it SPAMS the `command_reply` instead of just saying it once, I know I would probably have to take it of the `for` loop but then `[i]` is not defined etc.

Comment: 2 possibility that I could understand what are you asking: instead of `arrayOfCommands.commands.length`, just do `arrayOfCommands.length`, and then inside of your loop you get `arrayOfCommands[i].command_name` OR remove the loop and just do `arrayOfCommands.command_name`

Comment: If I was to remove the loop, then it wouldn't be able to check each command (I have more than one, this was just for example).

Comment: I don't think this loop is responsible for the spam since you send one message and then return.  You must have another loop outside the function, or your sendMessage method is broken.

Comment: @James However, when I change the line `message.channel.sendMessage(arrayOfCommands.commands[i].command_reply);` to `message.channel.sendMessage("yes");` it only says it once, not sure what the issue is.

Comment: Multiple equivalent commands in the commands array?

Comment: Nope, I cleared it for testing and only put one in there. @James

Comment: what wraps the fs.readFile(..) call?

Comment: @KyleRichardson it is in the message event handler.

Comment: Can you post the code for the function calling your snippet as well as message.channel.sendMessage method?

Comment: @KyleRichardson It is built into the discord.js library. But see what I said above in the comment:  when I change the line `message.channel.sendMessage(arrayOfCommands.commands[i].comm‌​and_reply);` to` message.channel.sendMessage("yes");` it doesn't spam.

Comment: I'm sorry, but without seeing the larger picture, I cannot help you. Hope you find some though!